# Creating an android app from an Eclipse Java project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, project

I know that questions like this have been asked before, and I have been sifting through them. So here is my situation: I have a decent amount of experience using Java, specifically Eclipse, and I have a game ready that from my current standards, could be uploaded to the Google marketplace.

However, I have the project saved as a Java project. How do I make this project into an android app? I have attempted using the ADT plugin for Ecclipse, and changing the nature of the project file but I am beyond confused regarding how to proceed.

Right now I can click: Run < Run as < Java application.
The goal is to be able to click: Run < Run as < Android application.

Comment: The user interface for an Android application is not built the same way as it is for a straight Java application, so it's not as simple as you would like.

Comment: But is it as complicated as I fear?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a streamlined way of doing it.  Is your game using Swing as a UI? JavaFX? Is it text?

Regardless, I imagine your game would need to be wrapped in an android activity in some way.  e.g. The activity can invoke the browser to run your applet (if your game is an applet).

I'd first create an android project, then copy your source from the java project into the android project.  The manifest (R) will be updated with the new resources, etc.

Then you have to finish wiring everything up.

Comment: I tried doing this but nearly all of my imports such as JFrame, actionlistener, etc. won't work. Do I need to do something special here, or are they simply incompatible and I must re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I think you, and everyone that wants to start developing for a new technology, MUST start reading the main concepts like the architecture and main components of that technology. Then you will realize that you don't have to re-invent the whell but yes, you have to change and add some things to let your API support more than one frontend.

Comment: android graphics is very different from the java one. Android has its personal graphic components!!

Answer (score 1):

It's going to take more than that.  Android has it's own UI system and lifecycle that differs from raw Java. Depending on how you've written the game you may be able to reuse a lot of the drawing and logic code but you going to need to make a lot of changes to the input and allowing multiple screen sizes.

Without seeing your code I can say exactly what you'll need to do but I can tell you it's not going to be as simple as Run As... Android Application.

Answer (score 0):

Although android apps are written in Java code, this doesn't means that it is possible to "translate" a java program or a game in an android app simply clicking a button.

If the game are complex I suggest that you rewrite the game using a framework for develop android game!! You can reuse some logic but sure you have to create all the graphics and readapt the game to run in android devices.

GOOD WORK!!
Be patient and star from here:
[Androi Developers](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You can implement the application logic in Android in the same way that you used in Java, but you cannot simply convert the java project into Android project. Some packages used in your java project (like swing) can't be used in Android.